# Error NullPOinterException in Android, help please

Tags: java, android

I'm so cunfused with this error. I hope there is someone who can help me.
this is my Error :

```
08-30 00:24:29.349: E/AndroidRuntime(2139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3318)
```

and this is my Code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ViewPager vPager;
private vpAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new vpAdapter();
    vPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
   private class vpAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 4;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return view==((LinearLayout)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)container.getContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = null;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.satu, null);
        break;
    case 1:
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.dua, null);
        break;
    case 2:
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.tiga, null);
        break;
    case 3:
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.empat, null);
        break;
    }
((ViewPager)container).addView(v,0);
return true;        
}

}
```

I have tried many ways but failed. such as changing the position of the break and change the position view group. did I forget to import a library or something? please help its the master here :)
I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.
Thanks Before :)

Comment: add the full log trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View is null.

You have this

```
   View v = null;
```

But i don't see you initializing view to the inflated layout any where. You only inlflate the layout. Hence you get `NullPointerException`. In your switch case initialize your views v and also cast it to view

```
   v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowimage,null, false);
```

Also return

```
   return v; // and not return true;
```

Comment: So in your all `case 0` to `case 3` use `v=inflater...` as in this answer !

Comment: so, after null, I have to add a "false" statement ?

Comment: @AndiAlif why do you need false. you have the break and you should return view `v` not true

Answer (score 0):

Its returning null pointer exception because here "v" is null. Change the switch condition to following,

```
 switch(position){
        case 0:
           v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.satu, null);
            break;
        case 1:
          v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.dua, null);
            break;
        case 2:
            v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tiga, null);
            break;
        case 3:
           v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.empat, null);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)container.getContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = null;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.satu, null);
        break;
    case 1:
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dua, null);
        break;
    case 2:
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tiga, null);
        break;
    case 3:
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.empat, null);
        break;
    }

return v;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your View is null-

> You are inflating XML Layout but not assigning in to the view.

Assign view in to your switch-

Like -

```
 v=(View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.satu, null);
```

and return the view not Boolean value-

```
 return v;
```